# Adobe Captivate: Prevent states from looping back to the beginning

Tags: adobe-captivate

Using Adobe Captivate 9. I have a text box which changes states to show different info on a single slide.
On the slide there is a forward and back button which changes the state of the text box. When clicking the next button on the last state it goes back to the first state. Is there a way to prevent this? Or hide the next button when on the final state.

Comment: You don’t say what action is assigned to the button to control the state, but there would have to be an explicit instruction on that action to return to the initial state if it’s on the last state. It won’t do that by itself. Remove whatever instruction that is.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an advanced action to control moving through the state. First creat a variable that equals 0. Second create an advanced action that adds 1 to the variable each time you click the the next button to move through the state (-1 for the previous button). On a new tab in the advanced action, create a conditional action (if variable = number of clicks to get to last state, then hide button). Do the same for the previous button (if variable = 0, then hide previous button).  You will also want one to show the buttons (if variable is not equal to 0, then show previous button) and (if variable is not equal to number of clicks, then show next button).